# SQL query - order yes and no by quarter

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by

I have following table:

```
id|overtime| date
--+--------+-----------
1 | yes    | 2017-03-10
2 | no     | 2017-07-16
3 | yes    | 2017-01-22
4 | no     | 2017-07-14
```

Now I want to sum the `yes`s and `no`s and order them by the quarter (`Q1`,`Q2`,`Q3`,`Q4`):

```
yes| no| quarter
---+---+---------------
13 |  4| Q1
2  |  5| Q2
8  | 14| Q3
12 | 12| Q4
```

My solution:

```
SELECT 
    (select count(*) As sum_yes from dashboard where overtime = 'Yes' ) as yes,
    (select count(*) As sum_no from dashboard where overtime = 'No' ) as no, 
    (SELECT quarter(date) as quarter from dashboard) 
group by quarter
```

I know it does not work. Very happy to get some help.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select year(date) as yyyy, quarter(date) as q,
       sum(overtime = 'Yes') as yes,
       sum(overtime = 'No') as no
from dashboard
group by yyyy, q;
```

Note that this includes the year.  I interpret "quarter" as distinguishing by year.  If you want to combine data from multiple years, then remove that component.

MySQL treats a boolean as an integer in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.

Answer (score 1):

So you want one row per quarter...

```
...
FROM dashboard
GROUP BY quarter(date);
```

Then you'd like to get one column with the count of those row where `overtime = 'Yes'`:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN overtime = 'Yes' THEN 1 END) as yes,
  ...
```

And one more for no

```
  ...
  COUNT(CASE WHEN overtime = 'No' THEN 1 END) as yes,
  ...
```

That's it. The `case` expression maps the matching rows to 1, while it maps the non mapping rows to `null` (due to the implied `else null` clause).

Just add the quarter column and you are done.

More about this technique: 
http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: Thank you Markus! it works fine!
 Here is my query: SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN overtime = 'Yes' THEN 1 END) as Ja,
COUNT(CASE WHEN overtime = 'No' THEN 1 END) as Nein,
quarter(date) as Quartal FROM dashboard GROUP BY Quartal